# Is there any alternative option(GUI) for resizing disk partitions?

Tags: partitioning, gui, resize

I want to resize my disk partition in my device but the applications like **disks** and **Gparted** is not working.
So is there any **GUI alternative** for Resizing and Re-allocating memory of our Physical disks?

As you can see the minimum and maximum size is the same so we cannot resize

[image: 1]

Comment: You can't resize on a running system.

Comment: Yes there are alternatives, eg. Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-Studio come with *KDE Partition Manager* as it's using the Qt5 libraries those *flavors* use, however it has the same limitations as `gparted` etc...  You can't alter the size of some *file-system* types whilst they are being used.  *ie. they prevent a operator from causing the OS from crashing & thus not only having the session lost, but also losing any data on the partition due to corruption when the system crashed*